# Pause Javascript for a few seconds on click

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, setinterval

Ok i know this has to be a topic discussed earlier, but all the answers I found were a little complicated considering I'm new and still in the process of learning javascript.

I have the following code in the head section of my html

```
<script>
function timedText() {
    setTimeout(function(){displayResult()},3000);
    setTimeout(function(){displayResult1()},7000);
    setTimeout(function(){displayResult2()},15000);
    setTimeout(function(){timedText()},18000);
}
</script>

<script>
function change() {
    setTimeout(function(){timedText()},1000);
}   
</script>

<script>
function displayResult() {
    document.getElementById("adimg_holder").style.bottom="0px";
    document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundPosition="bottom";
    document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundPosition="top";
    document.getElementById("button3").style.backgroundPosition="top";
}

function displayResult1() {
    document.getElementById("adimg_holder").style.bottom="370px";
    document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundPosition="top";
    document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundPosition="bottom";
    document.getElementById("button3").style.backgroundPosition="top";
}

function displayResult2() {
    document.getElementById("adimg_holder").style.bottom="739px";
    document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundPosition="top";
    document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundPosition="top";
    document.getElementById("button3").style.backgroundPosition="bottom";
}
</script>
```

and the following html

```
    <body onload="change()">
    <div class="banner_area">
    <div class="banner_wrapper">
        <img src="images/image_holder.png" />
        <div id="ad_holder">
            <div id="adimg_holder">
            <img class="ad_images" src="images/recruitment_banners.png" />
            <img class="ad_images" src="images/training_banners.png" />
            <img class="ad_images" src="images/staffing_banner.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ad_buttons">
        <div id="button1" style="background-image:url(images/buttonfirst.png);background-position:bottom;width:259px;height:41px" onclick="displayResult()"></div>
        <div id="button2" style="background-image:url(images/buttonsecond.png);width:259px;height:41px" onclick="displayResult1()"></div>
        <div id="button3" style="background-image:url(images/buttonthird.png);width:259px;height:41px" onclick="displayResult2()"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

So the buttons toggle different positions, and the script cycles through the positions at time intervals

Now what I'm trying to achieve is that when the positions are being cycled through, if I click on one of the button, it jumps to the related position and stays that way for a while (say a few seconds) and then continue with the loop.

Hope I've made my motive easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/PcZsT/12/

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function timedText() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    displayResult();
  },2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    displayResult1();
  },6000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    displayResult2();
  },14000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    timedText();
  },15000);
}

(function change() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    timedText();
  },1000);
}());

var locked = false;

function button1Handler() {
  moveTop();
  lockFor(3);
}

function button2Handler() {
  moveBottom();
  lockFor(3);
}

function lockFor(seconds) {
  locked = true;
  setTimeout(function () {
    locked = false;
  }, seconds * 1000);
}

function displayResult() {
  if (locked) return;
  moveTop();
}

function moveTop() {
  document.getElementById("adimg_holder").style.bottom="0px";
  document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundPosition="bottom";
  document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundPosition="top";
  document.getElementById("button3").style.backgroundPosition="top";
}

function displayResult1() {
  if (locked) return;
  moveMiddle();
}

function moveMiddle() {
  document.getElementById("adimg_holder").style.bottom="370px";
  document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundPosition="top";
  document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundPosition="bottom";
  document.getElementById("button3").style.backgroundPosition="top";
}

function displayResult2() {
  if (locked) return;
  moveBottom();
}

function moveBottom() {
  document.getElementById("adimg_holder").style.bottom="739px";
  document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundPosition="top";
  document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundPosition="top";
  document.getElementById("button3").style.backgroundPosition="bottom";
}
```

The functions above are the click handlers of respectively `button1` and `button2`.

I've also changed the `change`  function to бe IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) but it's not necessary, you don't have to do it because you want to be invoked `onload`.

Comment: doesn't seem to work well in the Jsfiddle.. it reacts a lil while after clicking the button.

Comment: It reacts a second after you've clicked on the green or blue block.
I've updated my answer with a little more improved version...I'll update the fiddle too...if it loads one day...

Comment: At last jsfiddle loaded...I've updated the fiddle. But when you click on the green or blue divs (buttons) then after 1 second the images are being moved. Of course the `change` method is still running on each 18000 milliseconds so the images could move anytime when `change` call any method..

Comment: Well thanx a ton for taking the trouble of looking into my problem. Thing is I want the position to change instantly on click and then stay that way for a while (say 3-5 seconds) and then continue to automatically toggle automatically

Comment: You want it to be locked (not moving) until the button is clicked or just block for 3-5 seconds after the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of the setTimeout timing function itself.

write a function as:

```
function calldesiredFunctionafterPause (functionTobeCalled){

   setTimeout(function(){functionTobeCalled,1000}) //increase the millisec as needed
}
```

and on the onClick call this function and pass the function name as parameter.

This will make the onclick function to be delayed for the required time

Comment: i have done a mistake in the code...correct it as  setTimeout( function(){ functionTobeCalled(); },1000)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need so much code : just make one displayResult function that will call itself over and over :

```
var scrollParam = {        scrollPos : 0,         // current pos
                           scrollIncr : 370,      // incr in px each call
                           loopScrollAfter : 700  // set scrollPos to >0 if above that number
                           delay : 3000,          // std scroll delay 
                           whichIsOnTop : 0,      // index of the topmost item (button)
                           pauseDelay : 1000,     // added delay if someone clicks
                           pauseRequired : 0 };   // current required click delay

var mainItem = document.getElementById("adimg_holder");

function displayResult()
 {
   mainItem.style.bottom=scrollParam.scrollPos +"px";
   scrollParam.scrollPos += scrollParam.scrollIncr;
   if (scrollParam.scrollPos>scrollParam.loopScrollAfter) scrollParam.scrollPos=0;

   setBackgroundPosition("button1",0);
   setBackgroundPosition("button2",1);
   setBackgroundPosition("button3",2);
   scrollParam.whichIsOnTop = (scrollParam.whichIsOnTop + 1) % 3;

   // now setup the next call, taking into account if a pause is required
   var requiredDelay = scrollParam.delay;
   if (scrollParam.pauseRequired >0) { 
            requiredDelay += scrollParam.pauseRequired;  
            scrollParam.pauseRequired=0;
           }
   setTimeout(displayResult, requiredDelay);
 }

 var setBackgroundPosition(itemName, index ) {             
    document.getElementById(itemName).style.backgroundPosition=topOrBottom(index ); 
  };

 // returns "top" for the right index (==scrollParam.whichIsOnTop) and "bottom" for the others
 var topOrBottom(thisIndex) { return (thisIndex == scrollParam.whichIsOnTop) ? "top" : "bottom"; };

 // in the button click handler you should use :
 scrollParam.pauseRequired += scrollParam.pauseDelay;

 // to launch the scroll, just call :
 displayResult();                        // in the loaded() event handler for example.
```

Rq : you can change easily the parameters to have a smoother scrolling if you like.

Comment: Thanx for comming up with the script but as mentioned in the question, im new to javascript and intend on learning more. Your script seems professional, but I still find it tough to understand what happens when it executes. That's the reason for me asking for a simpler script. Basically im taking it slow, as long as I learn through the process. Thanx a ton though...